# Expected Values

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value

I wish to calculate $E[(aXY)^{0.5}]$
whee $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed and independent. Moreover, $a$ is a constant. Given
independence, can I rewrite the above as
$$
E[(aXY)^{0.5}]=E[(a^{0.5}X^{0.5}Y^{0.5})]=a^{0.5}E[X^{0.5}]E[Y^{0.5}]?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Also note the comment by whuber below.

Comment: This will be correct when $a$, $X$, and $Y$ are almost surely positive.  It will fail, for instance, in the case $a=-1$, $X$ is supported on an interval of negative numbers, and $Y$ is supported on an interval of positive numbers.